# KeePass Portable with Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keepass

I downloaded Keepass Professional Portable edition and it works perfect on Windows but I can't seem to open `.exe` files on mac. I'm not sure if it's because school computers won't allow it or if I'm just not entirely familiar with mac. Any suggsetions on how I can run my KeePass portable on mac? I have mono on my flashdrive and tried using the batch file method but I have no idea how to make batch files on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Macs don't run .exe files.  In this case, "portable" means any Windows machine.

Comment: Not sure, the keepass support says something about [portable with Mono](http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html#monoportable) but the mono is an exe file also so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: The Windows version of Mono is a .exe; you'll need the [OS X version of Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX) instead.